# Converting Stanford dependency relation to dot format

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

I am a newbie to this field. I have dependency relation in this form:

```
amod(clarity-2, sound-1)
nsubj(good-6, clarity-2)
cop(good-6, is-3)
advmod(good-6, also-4)
neg(good-6, not-5)
root(ROOT-0, good-6)
nsubj(ok-10, camera-8)
cop(ok-10, is-9)
ccomp(good-6, ok-10)
```

As mentioned in the links we have to convert this dependency relation to dot format and then use Graphviz for drawing a 'dependency tree'. I am not able to understand how to pass this dependency relation to toDotFormat() function of edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph. When I give this string, 'amod(clarity-2, sound-1)' as input to toDotFormat() am getting the output in this form digraph amod(clarity-2, sound-1) { }.
I am trying the solution given here [how to get a dependency tree with Stanford NLP parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468872/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-with-stanford-nlp-parser/28493020#28493020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`toDotFormat`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html#toDotFormat--) on an entire dependency tree. How have you generated these dependency trees in the first place?

If you're using the StanfordCoreNLP pipeline, adding in the `toDotFormat` call is easy:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, depparse");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

String text = "This is a sentence I want to parse.";
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

pipeline.annotate(document);

// these are all the sentences in this document
// a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
  // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
  SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
  System.out.println(dependencies.toDotFormat());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jon Gauthier!  Yes, am using Stanford parser only, link here http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net/lingstruc.html . Could you please clarify me what is the "String text" here, is it the file name containing the dependency relations as I mentioned above? I am presently using stanford-tregex.jat file for edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph class. I am getting the error error: cannot find symbol
  Annotation document = new Annotation(text); Could you please help me with this!

Comment: Updated with an example `text` value — this is whatever sentence content you want to have parsed. You should use Stanford CoreNLP or the Stanford Parser for this. You can download the CoreNLP package from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

Comment: Hurray! Now am able to generate dot format file. Thanks a lot @Jon Gauthier! :)

Comment: Glad it's working, @VenkataAnusha! If this resolves your question, can you please mark this answer as accepted? (green check mark below the voting buttons to the left)