# Dependency Tree with Stanza

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanza (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/), and I'd like to take the dependency tree and convert it to an image, similar to what's done here ([how to get a dependency tree with Stanford NLP parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468872/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-with-stanford-nlp-parser)).

However, I've downloaded the stanza source code and can't seem to find anything similar to the to_dot() method. How should I proceed to do this in Stanza?