# Depict a NLTK CoreNLPParser output visually using NLTK Tree or another method

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp, pretty-print

I'm using CoreNLPParser from NLTK to get an Stanford NLP Parser output. The code

```
parser = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000')
result = list(parser.raw_parse(sentence))
print(result)
```

Results in

```
 [Tree('ROOT', [Tree('SINV', [Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('JJ', ['Several']), Tree('NNS', ['times'])]), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['an']), Tree('NN', ['hour'])])]), Tree(',', [',']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NN', ['lava'])])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBZ', ['shoots']), Tree('PRT', [Tree('IN', ['out'])]), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['of']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['a']), Tree('NN', ['volcano'])]), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['in']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NNP', ['Italy'])])])])])])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBD', ['called'])]), Tree('NP', [Tree('NNP', ['Stomboli'])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])])]
```

How do I get to print this in a better visual format such as  those available via NLTK's pretty_print function? I've tried to convert result (with and without the creation of a list) to a NLTK Tree using methods such as fromstring and fromlist with no success. I tried replicating the method from [how to get a dependency tree with Stanford NLP parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468872/how-to-get-a-dependency-tree-with-stanford-nlp-parser) for the constituency tree I'm trying to get but no luck there either. Any help would be appreciated.